# Django download CSV from SQL DB and render template

Tags: python, django, postgresql, csv

This is a bit of a fully loaded question...

So I have a Django app with a PostgreSQL DB. I would like to offer an option where the user can download a specific set of tables from the DB as a csv file.

```
├── app
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── forms.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── templates
│   │   └── anthropometrics
│   │       ├── form.html
│   │       └── index.html
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
```

So here is an example app that I have. I would like to export pretty much everything in models.py (as a CSV). When I do so, however, I would like to reroute back to the original page.

So I will have my index.html:

```
<div class="container">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
      <div class="container-fluid">
          {% if user.is_authenticated %}
              <a href="{% url 'app:form' %}"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn">Enter Data</button></a>
              <a href="{% url 'app:view' %}"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn">View Data</button></a>
              <a href="{% url 'app:download' %}"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn">GET Data</button></a>
          {% endif %}
      </div>
  </nav>

{% block next %}{% endblock %}
```

EDIT:

The app button will render this view in `views.py`

```
def get_model_fields(model):
    return model._meta.fields
def download(request):
    BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))+"/anthropometrics"
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=data.csv'
    writer = csv.writer(response)
    for model in [base,question1,question2,question3,question4]:
        name = model.__name__
        # Write headers to CSV file
        fields = get_model_fields(model)
        if fields:
            headers = fields
        else:
            headers = []
            for field in model._meta.fields:
                headers.append(field.name)
        writer.writerow(headers)
        # Write data to CSV file
        for obj in model.objects.all():
            row = []
            for field in headers:
                if field in headers:
                    val = getattr(obj, field.name)
                    if callable(val):
                        val = val()
                    row.append(val)
            writer.writerow(row)
        # Return CSV file to browser as download
    return response
```

The example code above is like for serving just a normal text file. I imagine it would be something close to this using `csv` from `import csv`

Any help?

Here's my models.py:

```
class base(models.Model):
    mothers_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    date = models.DateField()
    data_collector = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class question1(models.Model):
    question1_base = models.OneToOneField(base, primary_key=True)
    question1_1a_in_cm  = models.IntegerField(default=False)
    question1_1a_in_in  = models.IntegerField(default=False)
    question1_1b_in_kg  = models.IntegerField(default=False)
    question1_1b_in_lbs = models.IntegerField(default=False)
class question2(models.Model):
    question2_base = models.OneToOneField(base, primary_key=True)
    question2_2a = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=get_choices(2, 'YES', 'NO'))
    question2_2a_explanation = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    question2_2b = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=get_choices(2, 'YES', 'NO'))
    question2_2b_explanation = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
class question3(models.Model):
    question3_base = models.OneToOneField(base, primary_key=True)
    question3_3a_in_cm  = models.IntegerField(default=False)
    question3_3a_in_in  = models.IntegerField(default=False)
    question3_3b_in_kg  = models.IntegerField(default=False)
    question3_3b_in_lbs = models.IntegerField(default=False)
class question4(models.Model):
    question4_base = models.OneToOneField(base, primary_key=True)
    question4_4a_in_cm = models.IntegerField(default=False)
    question4_4a_in_in = models.IntegerField(default=False)
    question4_4a_not_known = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=get_choices(1, 'YES'), null=True, blank=True)
    question4_4b_in_kg = models.IntegerField(default=False)
    question4_4b_in_lbs = models.IntegerField(default=False)
    question4_4b_not_known = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=get_choices(1, 'YES'), null=True, blank=True)
    question4_4c = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=get_choices(3, 'Hospital/Clinic Health Card', 'Mother', 'Other'))
    question4_4d = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=get_choices(2, 'YES', 'NO'))
    question4_4d_explanation = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    question4_4e = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=get_choices(2, 'YES', 'NO'))
    question4_4e_explanation = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
```

I am so freaking close, I just can't figure out how to add multiple classes from models.py (tables in SQL) to the same csv file

Comment: Yes, use the `csv` module.  There are plenty of examples online on how to return a `.csv` file in Django (including in the Django docs).

Comment: How would I get those specific tables in the postgres table into the csv?

Comment: What have you tried?  You haven't provided any model code (so we don't know if there is anything special about your models), you haven't shown that you've made any effort reading the documentation or any of the online resources (which are bountiful).  I'll stretch pretty far to help someone that makes an effort, but it's not worth my time to do your work for you (sorry).

Comment: I have actually done a lot to learn this on my own @thebjorn . I have posted my updated code. And I am not asking you to do my job for me... I have refined my post to the last bit: figuring out how to add multiple tables to that csv file before returning from the view

Comment: Congratulations on fixing your issue. I hope you understand that I wasn't trying to be mean with my comments, but the more information you put into your question the higher the likelihood of someone wanting to help you.  This is especially important regarding what you've tried and what information you've found, otherwise you'll get that exact information and everyone's time has been wasted: eg. with only the information in the original question I would have sent you to the first hit for "django docs csv", and "django model csv export" (this comment is too long to fit the links).

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem. I just had the code slightly in views.py. The most recent EDIT has the correct code